# Mysql confusion with LIMIT function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the following SQL query in MySQL.

```
"SELECT SUBSTRING(invoices.dateCreated, 1, 7) AS month, 
        account.name AS accountName, 
        account.id AS accountId, 
        invoices.invId AS invoiceId, 
        productType.title AS productTitle, 
        sum(invoiceItems.cost*invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalValue,
        sum(invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalQuantity
 FROM account LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.accountId = account.id
          LEFT JOIN invoiceItems ON invoices.id = invoiceItems.invoiceId
      LEFT JOIN productType ON invoiceItems.productTypeId = productType.id
 WHERE invoices.statusId != 'S62FD452B1D4'
 GROUP BY invoiceItems.productTypeId, invoices.invId   
 ORDER BY month DESC, accountName ASC, invoices.id ASC    
 LIMIT ".$start_limit.", ".$records_per_page.";"
```

This works fine with out the section to limit the query. However when I add the limit section, the variables `$start_limit` & `$records_per_page` have no value, whereas if i jig the lines around the variables are making it into the query. this is also the case when I change the quotation marks around the variables e.g to `'.$start_limit.'`.
However the query does not seem to function with this.

Any advice or help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

The values for the two variables are 100% definitely being passed in. and in this example they are simply, start limit = 0 and end limit (per page) = 50.
I have checked and 50 is well below the limit.

The problem is that when I see the SQL error pop up it says:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(invoices.dateCreated, 1, 7) AS month, 
       account.name AS accountName, 
       account.id AS accountId, 
       invoices.invId AS invoiceId, 
       productType.title AS productTitle, 
       sum(invoiceItems.cost*invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalValue,
       sum(invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalQuantity 
FROM account LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.accountId = account.id 
             LEFT JOIN invoiceItems ON invoices.id = invoiceItems.invoiceId 
             LEFT JOIN productType ON invoiceItems.productTypeId = productType.id 
WHERE invoices.statusId != 'S62FD452B1D4' 
GROUP BY invoiceItems.productTypeId, invoices.invId 
ORDER BY month DESC, accountName ASC, invoices.id ASC 
LIMIT , ;
```

and if i change things around to see if the variables are there we do get:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(invoices.dateCreated, 1, 7) AS month, 
       account.name AS accountName, 
       account.id AS accountId, 
       invoices.invId AS invoiceId, 
       productType.title AS productTitle, 
       sum(invoiceItems.cost*invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalValue, 
       sum(invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalQuantity 
FROM account LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.accountId = account.id 
             LEFT JOIN invoiceItems ON invoices.id = invoiceItems.invoiceId 
             LEFT JOIN productType ON invoiceItems.productTypeId = productType.id 
WHERE invoices.statusId != 'S62FD452B1D4' 
GROUP BY invoiceItems.productTypeId, invoices.invId 
ORDER BY month DESC, accountName ASC, invoices.id ASC 
LIMIT '.0.', '.50.' ;
```

neither of these values are user supplied. so thats not too much of a problem. I am unsure as to why the variables are behaving unusually in this 1 query from hundred similar 1s ive have done that do the same thing fine. the only difference in this one is the number of groupings and orderings. would this make a difference?

Comment: It should work like this. What are the values of `$start_limit` and `$records_per_page`?

Comment: Where you have $start_limit & $records_per_page defined?

Comment: Try with some number for both the variables and see the result it it works fine then thr is a problem in variables

Comment: Try echo in both variables inside ur query

Comment: Can we see where the query string is being used? Is it being assigned to a variable, used in a custom library, ...? I don't see any reason why two populated values and the concatenation used (as shown) would fail.

Comment: What are those dots doing around your $start_limit and $records_per_page? That looks like a problem.

Comment: my bad. the dots are just how i have been trying a wild range of possibilies when copying it on this question. the dots are actually ". mysql_real_escape_string($start_limit) .", ". mysql_real_escape_string($records_per_page) .";";   which has the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$start_limit` and/or `$records_per_page` are unpopulated you're going to have issues. However, if you default them to standard values before placing them in the query if you wish:

```
// default them values to 0 and 50
$start_limit = empty($start_limit) ? 0 : $start_limit;
$records_per_page = empty($records_per_page) ? 50 : $records_per_page;
// may also want to check (empty(...) || $var < 0 || $var > $threshold) as well.
```

Then go about your business:

```
$sql = "SELECT " . /* ... */ " LIMIT " . $start_limit . "," . $records_per_page;
```

I should note though that if either (or both) are these are user-supplied (or the user has any opportunity to change these values) I would sanitize them first before placing them in the query. e.g.

```
$start_limit = (int) $_REQUEST['start_limit'];
if ($start_limit < 0) // can't be <0
  $start_limit = 0;

$records_per_page = (int) $_REQUEST['records_per_page'];
if ($records_per_page < 10) // can't be <10
  $records_per_page = 10;
else if ($records_per_page > 100) // can't be >100
  $records_per_page = 100;
```

Then you're making sure `$start_limit` doesn't contain anything threatening like `;SELECT password FROM admin_table;`. ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

*Your question is a bit ambiguous though, so if I'm off track please update the question and I will do the same with my answer*

Comment: ok thanks. neither of these values are user supplied. so thats not too much of a problem. I am still unsure as to why the variables are behaving unusually in this 1 query from hundred similar 1s ive have done that do the same thing fine. the only difference in this one is the number of groupings and orderings. would this make a difference?

Comment: @mrsorbose: As I see it (and can only judged based on what you've supplied) the concatenation is failing. I would either try using `{$start_limit}` within the quotes  and not break out the variables from the string (e.g. `...LIMIT {$start_limit},{$records_per_page};"`) or use `sprintf()` and supply the two as arguments (echoing either results to see the difference). It's either that, or you have a mis-match `"` somewhere else on the page that's interfering with this statement.

Comment: @mrsorbose: Did you end up discovering the issue?

Comment: Well, Using the sprintf seemed to do the trick. Although looking at it with a refreshed mind I noticed that I was referring to the function later in the script, so may have had a problem with duplication. but shouldnt gave been a conflict of variables. am fairly new at this, so this still baffled me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The values of `$start_limit` and `$records_per_page` are probably invalid or out of range. Perhaps try logging them to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the PDO Extension for this?

Your code is prone to SQL Injection. Use the PDO or MySQLi Extensions.

Example using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT SUBSTRING(invoices.dateCreated, 1, 7) AS month, account.name AS accountName, account.id AS accountId, invoices.invId AS invoiceId, productType.title AS productTitle, sum(invoiceItems.cost*invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalValue, sum(invoiceItems.quantity) AS totalQuantity
             FROM account
             LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.accountId = account.id
             LEFT JOIN invoiceItems ON invoices.id = invoiceItems.invoiceId
             LEFT JOIN productType ON invoiceItems.productTypeId = productType.id
             WHERE invoices.statusId != 'S62FD452B1D4'
             GROUP BY invoiceItems.productTypeId, invoices.invId   
             ORDER BY month DESC, accountName ASC, invoices.id ASC    
             LIMIT ?, ?;"


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $start_limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
    // other codes here

?>
```

Comment: Though I 100% agree, PDO is the way to go, sometimes it's a little late in the game to be making this kind of change (too many places to update the change, and too little time before deadline).